# Show that if $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ are Cauchy sequences in X then $d(x_{n},y_{n})$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could someone help me through this problem?
Let $X$ be a metric space. Show that if $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$ then $d(x_{n},y_{n})$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Does this follow from the fact that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent?

Comment: Is the metric space complete?

Comment: @TenaliRaman You don't need the metric space to be complete, since the convergence in question is in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @BrettFrankel I just remember proving this for a complete metric space at some point, basically I had assumed $\{y_n\} \rightarrow y$ and $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ and used this to show $\{\langle x_n, y_n \rangle\} \rightarrow \langle x, y \rangle$. Then, showing $d(x_n, y_n)$ converges was quite easy. I have to check Davide's hint below to see how the same can be without assuming completeness.

Comment: @TenaliRaman: You can fix that proof by running it in the completion of $X$.

Comment: @breton This is problem 23 in chapter 3 of baby rudin. It gives a hint that is basically the ones below. In your post, $d(x_n,y_n)$ is a sequence, so it should be written $\{d(x_n,y_n)\}$ or similarly.

Comment: It does follow from this that Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ converge; however, I believe you will have to use that fact to prove this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially Davide Giraudo's approach, but somewhat shorter: The triangle inequality gives
$$d(x_m,y_m)\leq d(x_m,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y_m)$$
or
$$d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_m,x_n)+d(y_n,y_m)\ .$$
As the right side is symmetric in $m$ and $n$ we have in fact
$$\bigl|d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)\bigr|\leq d(x_m,x_n)+d(y_n,y_m)\ .$$

Comment: For the R.H.S ,each of the individual terms i.e  $d(x_{m},x_{n})$ , $d(x_{n},y_{n})$ ,$d(y_{n},y_{m})$ is a sequence right ? I am asking because in the book Introductory functional analysis, kreyszig uses $d(x_{n},x)$ to denote a sequence of real numbers $a_{n}$  while talking about convergence of sequence. So drawing analogy, In this case , would it be like using a triangle inequality on sequences ?
P.S in the book by kreyszig , he uses the following extended version of triangle inequality : $d(x_{n},y_{n}) \leq d(x_{n},x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y_{n})$ to answer the O.P

Comment: @warrior_monk: The $d(x_m,y_n)$, etc., are numbers, and among some of these numbers the triangle inequality holds. – Considering your referring to Kreyszig: It seems that there it is assumed that $X$ is complete, which is not the case in the above question.

Comment: Sir, from last inequality we can say $a_n=d(x_n,y_n)$ is Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence it converges in $\mathbb{R}$. am i correct ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use triangular inequality
$$|d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_m,y_m)|\leq |d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_n,y_m)|+|d(x_n,y_m)-d(x_m,y_m)|,$$
then the reversed triangular inequality $|d(x,y)-d(z,y)|\leq d(x,z)$.

Comment: In the reverse triangle inequality, the RHS should be $d(x,z)$.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, it was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent, so exists $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$  such that $x_n\to x$ , $y_n\to y$, then  by continuity of the metric, 
$$d(x_n,y_n)\to d(x,y).$$

Comment: I can not still use the continuity of the metric

Comment: $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences in $X$, not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a complete metric space then there exist $ x,y \in X $ such that $ d(x_n,x)   \rightarrow 0$ and $ d(y_n,y) \rightarrow 0$. Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \vert d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y) \vert & = & \vert d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y_n) + d(x,y_n) - d(x,y)\vert \\
                                 & \le & \vert d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y_n) \vert + \vert  d(x,y_n) - d(x,y)\vert \\
                                 & \le d(x_n,x) + d(y_n,y) \rightarrow 0 \\
 \end{eqnarray*}
If $X$ isn't complete, I dont believ the result is true because the natural candidate $d(x,y)$ maybe don't exist.

Comment: You don't need the limit points $x$ and $y$. Look at Davide's answer: the right hand side of the inequality can be estimated from above by $d(y_n,y_m) + d(x_n,x_m)$ which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $m,n$ large enough.